# How do I use a version of ODP.NET different to the one I built with?

Tags: oracle, odp.net, assemblyversions

I've got an app that is built with ODP.NET 2.111.6.20 - all the references in VS are set Specific Version to false, but when I try to run the app on a machine that only has 2.111.6.0, it throws an error saying it can't find the 2.111.6.20 assembly. How can I get my app to run with any version of ODP.NET 2.111?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the assembly is strongly signed, so you get the exception. You could use [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in your app.config file:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="ODP.NET"
                              publicKeyToken="PUT THE PUBLIC TOKEN HERE"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.111.6.20"
                             newVersion="2.111.6.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```